# Microsoft Web Services Enhancements SOAP Protocol Factory can't be selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

[image]
[image]
[image]

I need to use a Web service to send and receive large amounts of data from ref : [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx)

but it's disabled, please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you adding it from an ASP.NET project?

Comment: Yes, it's project with asp.net Framework 4.0 in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Do you need to check the first checkbox to enable the second?

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple solution :
There two ways to create a Web service:

- The first : File > New > Projet (Ctrl + Maj + N) > ASP.NET Web Service 
  **Application**
- The Second : File > New > web site ( Maj + Alt + N) > ASP.NET Web Service

If you encounter this problem : you used the first method.

**So, just use the second method** (File > New > web site ( Maj + Alt + N) > ASP.NET Web Service) to create your web service, and you will be able to check the second box in WSE Settings 3.0 panel.

For more details : http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.webservices.enhancements/2007-04/msg00008.html